# Does Java have the equivalent of @synthesize in Objective-C?

Tags: java, objective-c, groovy, getter-setter

I am learning Obj-C and discovered the `@synthesize` directive which generates accessor and mutator methods.

Groovy auto-generates getters/setters but I'm not sure if Java does.  Does Java have a similar feature in Java 7?

Comment: Not built in, but you could always write your own annotation processor.

Comment: Not sure if this is a question about Java 7, or an advertisement for Groovy or ObjectiveC.

Comment: **1.** Can't portions of Groovy's libraries be imported and used in regular Java?  **2.** If so, is this something can be added to a non-Groovy project, either on a project level or a class or attribute level?

Answer (score 3):

As everyone has said, the answer is no, however [Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/features/index.html) could be of interest

Answer (score 1):

No, java does not come with such a feature.

Answer (score 1):

No, if I'm not mistaken, not yet at least.

Answer (score 1):

Though Java does not, to my knowledge, have such a feature defined, several Java coding environments (such as Eclipse) produce automatic getters and setters under certain circumstances.